# Get selected index of filtered table

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have datagrid that bound to datatable at the view model, I have filter button that filters the relevant rows. I want to get the selected index after that the table was filtered

```
<DataGrid    
   DataContext="{Binding MyVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"                                  
   CanUserAddRows="False"
   IsReadOnly="True"
   SelectionUnit="FullRow"
   AutoGenerateColumns="False"
   SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndexDDG}"
   SelectedValue="{Binding SelectionValueDDG}" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding JobsViewDT, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

ViewModel:

```
 void FilterBtnCommand()
 {   
    JobsViewDT.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"DateTime >= {DateTime.Now} AND DateTime <= {DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)}";
 }
 ...
 public DataTable JobsViewDT
 {
     get{return jobsViewDT;}
        set
        {
            Set(() => JobsViewDT, ref jobsViewDT, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("JobsViewDT");
        }
 }
```

> but after that the table was filtered and I select some row, it treats the selected row index as it the original table and not as the filtered.

Comment: IMO it makes no sense to bind `SelectedIndex` and `SelectedValue` at the same time. Since you are also not setting `SelectedValuePath`, you should perhaps only bind the `SelectedItem` property, and retrieve the filtered index in the view model. It is also poinless to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and `Mode=TwoWay` on the ItemsSource Binding. It has no effect at all.

Comment: @Clemens Ok, but what about getting the selected index from the filtered table

Comment: Perhaps retrieve it in the view model, from the selected item. Why do you need it at all?